# Ratio of row value to sum of rows in a group using r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` in `r`, which I have summed and grouped.  I'd now like to find the ratio of the sum of `value` for each `ID` by `year` and `quarter`, to the total sum of `value` all groups by `year` and `quarter`.

This seems like a common enough question to ask data, but I can't figure out how to make the otherwise fabulous data.table return the answer.

The table i'm looking for would look like this (adding the column `pct_byQtrYr`):

```
    ID year quarter value pct_byQtrYr
 1:  A 2020       4   4.0       0.195
 2:  B 2020       4  10.5       0.512
 3:  C 2020       4   6.0       0.293
 4:  A 2021       1   6.6       0.293
 5:  B 2021       1  15.0       0.667
 6:  C 2021       1   0.9       0.040
 7:  A 2021       2   6.2       0.198
 8:  B 2021       2   9.8       0.313
 9:  C 2021       2  15.3       0.489
10:  A 2021       3   5.0       0.526
11:  B 2021       3   3.4       0.358
12:  C 2021       3   1.1       0.116
```

raw data is below:

```
dt <- data.table(
        ID = c( "A", "B", "C",
               "A", "B", "C",
               "A", "B", "C",
               "A", "B", "C"), 
        year = c(
                 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                 2021, 2021, 2021,
                 2021, 2021, 2021,
                 2021, 2021, 2021), 
        quarter = c(4, 4, 4, 
                    1, 1, 1,
                    2, 2, 2,
                    3, 3, 3), 
        value = c(4, 10.5, 6,
                  6.6, 15, 0.9, 
                  6.2, 9.8, 15.3,
                  5, 3.4, 1.1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prop.table` to get ratio for `value` in each `year` and `quarter`.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, pct_byQtrYr := prop.table(value), .(year, quarter)]
dt

#    ID year quarter value pct_byQtrYr
# 1:  A 2020       4   4.0   0.1951220
# 2:  B 2020       4  10.5   0.5121951
# 3:  C 2020       4   6.0   0.2926829
# 4:  A 2021       1   6.6   0.2933333
# 5:  B 2021       1  15.0   0.6666667
# 6:  C 2021       1   0.9   0.0400000
# 7:  A 2021       2   6.2   0.1980831
# 8:  B 2021       2   9.8   0.3130990
# 9:  C 2021       2  15.3   0.4888179
#10:  A 2021       3   5.0   0.5263158
#11:  B 2021       3   3.4   0.3578947
#12:  C 2021       3   1.1   0.1157895
```

This is similar to dividing `value` by `sum` of the group.

```
dt[, pct_byQtrYr := value/sum(value), .(year, quarter)]
```